# How to register class instance count in two separate files?

Tags: python, class, instance

So I have a python class `Driver` which has a method `drive` which essentially runs a loop forever. I have it set up so that with every new instance of the class, a counter goes up. So if I make two separate instances of the class in 2 different files and run them one after the other, will the one that runs second register that it's a 2nd instance of the class, and the counter go up to 2? Or does this only work for instance calls in the same file?

Comment: I assume by "separate" files you mean launching the same file in different processes (i.e. separate interpreters)?

Comment: Where's the counter that's being incremented defined? Is it a global variable, a class attribute, instance attribute or what? Please [edit] your question and add some code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the files on after another with the interpreter, then the counter will reset once you run the second file, since everything from the first file being run will have exited memory. If you need data to persist between running two different files, your best bet is to write it to an external file in the first file and then read it in the second.